# Как убрать количество товара на карточках товара Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Если в редактировании шаблона убрать галку "разрешить указание количества товара", то кол-во убирается и на детальной странице, а мне нужно убрать только на самой карточке товара.
В catalog.element/.default/card/template.php если удаляю кусок кода, то вообще все ломается, нельзя добавить в корзину товар. Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать??

```html
case 'quantity':
   if (!$haveOffers)
   {
      if ($actualItem['CAN_BUY'] && $arParams['USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY'])
      {
         ?>
         <div class="product-item-info-container product-item-hidden" data-entity="quantity-block">
            <div class="product-item-amount">
               <div class="product-item-amount-field-container">
                  <span class="product-item-amount-field-btn-minus no-select" id="<?=$itemIds['QUANTITY_DOWN']?>"></span>
                  <input class="product-item-amount-field" id="<?=$itemIds['QUANTITY']?>" type="number"
                     name="<?=$arParams['PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE']?>"
                     value="<?=$measureRatio?>">
                  <span class="product-item-amount-field-btn-plus no-select" id="<?=$itemIds['QUANTITY_UP']?>"></span>
                  <span class="product-item-amount-description-container">
                     <span id="<?=$itemIds['QUANTITY_MEASURE']?>">
                        <?=$actualItem['ITEM_MEASURE']['TITLE']?>
                     </span>
                     <span id="<?=$itemIds['PRICE_TOTAL']?>"></span>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <?
      }
   }
   elseif ($arParams['PRODUCT_DISPLAY_MODE'] === 'Y')
   {
      if ($arParams['USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY'])
      {
         ?>
         <div class="product-item-info-container product-item-hidden" data-entity="quantity-block">
            <div class="product-item-amount">
               <div class="product-item-amount-field-container">
                  <span class="product-item-amount-field-btn-minus no-select" id="<?=$itemIds['QUANTITY_DOWN']?>"></span>
                  <input class="product-item-amount-field" id="<?=$itemIds['QUANTITY']?>" type="number"
                     name="<?=$arParams['PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE']?>"
                     value="<?=$measureRatio?>">
                  <span class="product-item-amount-field-btn-plus no-select" id="<?=$itemIds['QUANTITY_UP']?>"></span>
                  <span class="product-item-amount-description-container">
                     <span id="<?=$itemIds['QUANTITY_MEASURE']?>"><?=$actualItem['ITEM_MEASURE']['TITLE']?></span>
                     <span id="<?=$itemIds['PRICE_TOTAL']?>"></span>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <?
      }
   }

   break;
```

Comment: Правите шаблон, пробуете убрать переменную оставить span с пробелом. После этого полностью сбрасываете кэш из админки. Только после этого проверяете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо он берет количество товара для добавления в корзину из куска кода.Я бы поставил display:none или visibility:hidden для элементов, которые вам нужно скрыть.Так скрипт будет брать количество 1, но клиент в браузере не будет видеть возможность уменьшить или увеличить количество товара.Подскажите еще что вы имеете ввиду под карточкой товара.В моем понимании карточка товара и есть детальная страница товара.